# Usin SimpleCursorAdapter confusion

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ContentProvider` implementation in my app which works fine. I have a table called `elements` where the user can store a bunch of information.

What I am doing is when the user opens the app, I pull this data out of the database, process it using the display options set by the user (Like change the string formats, time formats, date formats, number decimals etc), and then put it in `ListFragment` which using my own implementation of `ArrayAdapter`. User can of course change the preferences in the middle of the session, where I reload the data and reformat it and present it to the user. The user can click on an item in the list, and see more details of that item. I accomplish this by overriding `ListFragment.onListItemClick()`.

I have been reading about `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I am confused if the use of this would be more correct than using an `ArrayAdapter` for what I am doing. I am confused because I am not directly mapping the database data to the view. So should I be using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`? Also, the `_ID` column seems to be a requirement. I don't want to rename my table at this point. After a few articles and tutorials, I am not sure what to do. So any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Using a CursorAdapter together with a CursorLoader in your Fragment or Activity will solve a lot of issues like when to reload the data and refresh your views. You'll get rid of your pojos too if you implement it that way. The first time you do it might be kinda hard to learn and understand, but it'll become sort of boilerplate code to you. At least if you get the point where you want to sync data using a SyncAdapter and ContentObserver it'll be great. Go ahead and take a look at the CursorAdapter. For the most cases it's not that much different from using a BaseAdapter.

Comment: Thats sounds good. The logic I am using to flag when the data reloads is getting complex. Btw, I am not using a server so I don't think I will need a `SyncAdapter`. But yes, `CursorAdapter` sounds like something that will be a good fit. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: If you have any links where I can find a good explanation with some examples, please do post!

Comment: That one is a good start: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html